# <input> with added padding-left is a too big hyperlink

Tags: php, css, html, input

I'm trying to position my Search button on my website: http://testowa.portalo.pl

It's seems to be well positioned using padding-left, but the space on the left (where powered by Google is) that shouldn't work as a hyperlink is actually a big hyperlink. How to correct this ?

```
<form method="get" action="search.php" target="_top">
<input type="text" id="Szukaj" style="margin-top:42px; width: 563px;" name="q" size="107" maxlength="155" value="Wyszukiwarka" onfocus="onfocus=clearDefault(this)"/>
<label style="display: none">Prześlij formularz wyszukiwania</label>
<input type="image" src="files/szukaj.gif" id="Szukaj_Button" style="padding-top:36px; padding-left:500px; position:absolute"/>     
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="<?php include("ustawienia/google_search.inc.php");?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="forid" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="oe" value="UTF-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="cof" value="GALT:#CC0000;GL:1;DIV:#FFFFFF;VLC:663399;AH:center;BGC:FFFFFF;LBGC:336699;ALC:0066CC;LC:0066CC;T:333333;GFNT:0066CC;GIMP:0066CC;FORID:11" />
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="pl" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **padding-left**, use **margin-left**.  Padding adds to the inside of the object you are styling.  Margin adds to the outside.  Have a look the CSS Box Model for a better understanding: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp